# How do I call Linux syscall from kernel space?

Tags: linux-kernel, system-calls

I'm porting linux kernel module written for Linux 2.4 to work with Linux 2.6.
Some syscalls declared through `syscallN()` macros and wrapped in `set_fs()` calls were used in the code.
How can I still use sycalls in Linux 2.6 where those macros are absent?

I know it's a bad taste to use syscalls from kernel space and `syscallN()` macros are broken on most platforms. Any reasonable way to replace `getuid`, `geteuid`, `mknod`, `chown`, `unlink`, `sched_yield` syscalls in kernel space is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`current->uid` and `current->euid` can substitute for the first two.

`schedule()` should work for the last one.

The filesystem operations look more complicated: you might try and see if `sys_chown()`, `sys_mknod()`, and `sys_unlink()` are exported (available for use by any module).  If they work, great.  There are some [useful tips here](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8110).  Otherwise, you have to dig a little deeper:

The `chown` syscall is defined in `fs/open.c`.  At a glance I don't see why you couldn't copy that code into your own "kernel_chown" function and give it a try.

The `mknodat` and `unlink` syscalls are in `fs/namei.c`; they eventually wind up calling `vfs_mknod()` and `vfs_unlink()`, respectively.  Maybe you can duplicate that code or figure out how it's done from there.

Comment: current->uid and current->euid are no more available in 2.6.

Comment: It was present in early 2.6 kernels, but it looks like it was replaced with the `current_uid()` macro in 2.6.27.  See `include/linux/cred.h`.